# array_search returns 0 when searching BOTH array from fetch_array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

nI´m trying to retrieve the numeric index of a particular column in my database. I need to access it from both numeric and associative indexes, so I need the fetch to be BOTH.

Here is the sample code:

```
$data = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
$student = mysqli_fetch_array($data) or die(mysql_error());

$index = array_search("columnName", array_keys($student));
```

It always returns 0 no matter what "columnName" I place into it. I managed to work this around with a loop or having two arrays, one numeric and other associative, but I´d like to understand why does´t this work...

Comment: What does `array_keys($student)` return?

Comment: It returns an array where the keys are my table´s numeric index and the values are my column names. If I call it in a `foreach (array_keys($student) as $keys=>$values) echo $keys.$values` they display normally.

Comment: My guess is that is what you want it to be. Please do `var_dump(array_keys($student))` and show us what it is

Comment: array(46) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> string(2) "id" [2]=> int(1) [3]=> string(4) "nome" [4]=> int(2) [5]=> string(9) "sobrenome" [6]=> int(3) [7]=> string(5) "idade" [8]=> int(4) [9]=> string(11) "instrumento" [10]=> int(5) [11]=> string(3) "dia" [12]=> int(6) }

Comment: Might this `[0]=>int(0)` be the problem?

Comment: Yes, I added an answer that solves it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a value that is 0. Because 0 == 'id'. But you can set the third parameter to true to make a strict match. So it would be:

```
$index = array_search('columnName', array_keys($student), true);
```

Comment: PHP will case 'id' to an int which is 0 and 0 == 0. true means that === is used which will compare that the types are the same also

Comment: And why does PHP change 'id' to INT 0? Thank you very much, by the way!

Comment: Because when you use == PHP tries to make them into the same type before comparing them.

Answer (score 3):

This ([array_search](https://www.php.net/array_search)) may returns `Boolean` false on failure or `integer(index of item)` value:

> **Warning** This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
> non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
> Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
> return value of this function.

For example, this will return `0` but it's the first index (found):

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
$key = array_search('blue', $array); // 0
if(getType($key) == 'boolean'){
    // not found
}
```

Result is `0` here and if it's `integer` then it's the index of first item. So make sure that, whether the `0` is found `index` or not. You may set the third parameter to `true` to overcome this problem:

> **strict** If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the
> array_search() function will search for identical elements in the
> haystack. This means it will also check the types of the needle in the
> haystack, and objects must be the same instance.

So, using a strict comparison you may ensure the appropriate result:

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
$key = array_search('blue', $array, true);
if($key !== false) {
    // Found the index in $key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?:

```
$arrayMap = array();
foreach( array_keys( $array ) as $index => $key ) {
     $arrayMap[] = array(
          'index' => $index,//position 
          'key' => $key,//text key
          'value' => $array[$key]  //value
     );
}
```